# Drawing with Winforms

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, drawing, paint

I want to get myself a bit of WinForm Graphics knowledge, so I'm rewriting my small 2D editor from XNA to WinForm Graphics-only.

Now, I made myself a new UserControl for the tileset, but as I've seen, the `Paint` method is only called at the initialization of the control. Since I want to permanently repaint my control (or at least via `MouseOver` event to save a bit of performance), I heard the `Invalidate()` method gets the Control to repaint itself, but that is **way** too unperformant.

Is there any way to let my UserControl paint itself via code, without having these performance-issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Paint` method is *not* only called at the initialization of the control. It is called every time that the control needs to be repainted. This, of course, happens when the control is first created. It also happens when your application is minimized then restored, when another window is moved over your app that obscures its contents and then removed, and so on. It also happens when you invalidate the control's client area using the `Invalidate` method or equivalents. This was done early in the development of Windows as a performance optimization—there's no need to repaint something that hasn't changed!

If you want to force the control to be repainted, you should call the [`Invalidate` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah9zhk07.aspx) and specify a particular region of the client area to be repainted.

I have no idea what you mean about "that is **way** too unperformant". It's impossible for the `Invalidate` method to be slow. All it does is set a flag that tells Windows your control needs to be redrawn whenever it is idle (not processing any other messages).

If you want to force Windows to repaint your control *immediately* (without waiting for it to be idle; another performance optimization built into Windows from the early days), call the [`Update` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update.aspx), which forces an immediate redraw of all invalidated regions.

The only way it could be slow is if your *drawing* code is slow inside of the `Paint` event handler method. And obviously I can't tell you how to optimize that code without seeing it first.

---

> Is there anyway to let my UserControl paint itself via code, without having these performance-issues?

The `Paint` event is precisely how and where controls should paint themselves. That's why it's there.

If you *don't* paint in the `Paint` event, anything that you paint will be erased the next time that the control is repainted (which, as mentioned earlier, can happen in response to any number of expected and unexpected occurrences).

Sometimes, though, it makes sense to paint temporary objects into the control's client area (such as showing a drag rectangle in response to a `MouseDown` event). In that case, you can obtain an instance of the `Graphics` class (which is typically passed as an argument to your `Paint` event handler method, and on which you call methods to do your drawing) at any time. You do this by calling the [`CreateGraphics` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics.aspx) on your control, which returns a `Graphics` object. You then draw into/onto the `Graphics` object obtained just as you would inside of the `Paint` event handler method.

Obviously this can't/won't be any faster than the drawing code inside of the `Paint` event handler method (if that is in fact the culprit), but it will cause the screen to be updated *immediately* rather than whenever the control is idle and not processing any other messages.

I'll reiterate again that this approach should be used *only* to provide immediately and **temporary** feedback, as everything you draw will be erased the next time that the control is redrawn. When that happens, the `Paint` event is raised, and your code inside that method handler runs, which doesn't know anything about what you drew on some other one-off occasion. That's why everything should happen inside of the `Paint` event handler method, and you should call `Invalidate` (and perhaps, though not usually, `Update`) when some other event makes it necessary to repaint.

Comment: First of all - thanks for your answer. Well, maybe it's not a performance issue, but the time my MouseMove-Method waits for the Control to be repainted? I have a ScrollY-Variable in my Control, which should adjust the graphics' location and is adjusted by the vScrollbar at its side. So I have a vScrollbar_Scroll-Event, which updates the ScrollY-value and calls the Invalidate-Method of the scrollbar. But it's just very slow. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Okay, thanks to your advice, I've researched a bit further and solved the problem. I set the ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint and ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer flags to true and reduced my painting area and everythings working very smooth. Thanks!

Comment: @Harald: Hmm, yes. Double buffering is the standard approach for smoothing out UI updates. Usually it's indicated in response to flickering, not what you were describing as "slow". `AllPaintingInWmPaint` just means that the control doesn't erase itself first by handling the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message and painting the default color. Double buffering is provided by WinForms. It draws everything first into an offscreen buffer, then blits that offscreen buffer directly to the screen. This is helpful, because you don't see all the intermediate painting steps occur along the way.