# Why do my methods to draw on a form not work? ( C# )

Tags: c#, graphics

[SOLVED]
I'm trying to simulate "the game of life" both in console and by drawing it, but my form is plain and white. How can I make my methods usable?

I'm doing it as my first time c# code, in VisualStudio 2019, just to get along with object-based languages. I tried event-based drawing (mouseclicks, buttons) and everything was fine.

My form class looks like this:

```
public partial class Board : Form
{
    private int BOARDWIDTH;
    private int BOARDHEIGHT;
    private int cellSize;
    private bool paint = false; //ADDED IN
    private World world;
    Graphics drawArea;
    public Board(World world, int cellsize)
    {
        this.BOARDHEIGHT = world.getWorldHeight() * cellsize;
        this.BOARDWIDTH = world.getWorldWidth() * cellsize;
        InitializeComponent();
        drawingArea.SetBounds(0, 0, this.BOARDWIDTH, this.BOARDHEIGHT);
        drawArea = drawingArea.CreateGraphics();
        this.cellSize = cellsize;
        this.world = world;
    }
    public void updateBoard(World world)
    {
        this.world = world;
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) // ADDED IN (Basically previous DrawCell inside)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        if(paint)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x*this.cellSize, y*this.cellSize, 
this.cellSize, this.cellSize);

            if (this.world.getCellState(x, y))
            {
                rect.Height--;
                rect.Width--;
                using (Pen wPen = new Pen(Color.Black))
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(wPen, rect);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                using (SolidBrush bBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(bBrush, rect);
                }

            }
            paint = false;
        }
    }
    private void DrawCell(int x, int y) //CHANGED
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        paint = true;
    }
    public void DrawWorld(int refreshRate)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.world.getWorldHeight(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j <this.world.getWorldWidth(); j++)
            {
                DrawCell(j, i);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

and my main looks like this:

```
static void Main()
{
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        World world = new World(20, 20);
        world.createRandomWorld();
        Board board = new Board(world, 10);
        Application.Run(board);
        board.DrawWorld(10);
}
```

I want to get a grid of black/white squares, white with borders. Now the only thing I get is that my code is not crashing

[Edit] I added the `OnPaint` and changed a bit my `DrawCell` method and I have something now (it draws, yaaay) but I get only one cell, not the whole grid. Also, my `bool paint` solution feels like an workaround, not a proper way to do this. If anything, I'd love to see "proper" working code, besause I don't the definitions/examples that are on the web (microsoft page) don't show me how can I make it work my way ^.^

Comment: Is this WinForms? You have to [draw in the Paint event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996409/), not in the mouse or button click.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing with Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996409/drawing-with-winforms)

Comment: Firstly, as others have commented, you should only draw on the form in the forms `OnPaint` method override.  You should never use `CreateGraphics` in order to draw on a form.  Secondly, in your `Main` method, you call `Application.Run(board);` which is a blocking call so the next line never gets called until after the form closes.

Comment: Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..

Comment: 1.@ChrisDunaway If `Application.Run(board);` stops futrher code from executing how do I "make it work"? I want to call my `DrawWorld` method and paint on my form with it.
2.Okay, thanks to you I got it to work with `OnPaint` method override, but now my question is: how do I make it so that when I call `DrawWorld` , a whole grid of cells is drawn? Right now when I run my program only one cell is drawn.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to draw "this cell now", you should draw the entire `World` "on demand" whenever `OnPaint` is called.

You can cause a repaint by calling `Invalidate()` on the form, for instance when something in the `World` has changed. `OnPaint` will also be called automatically, for instance when your form is first shown, or when it reappears after having been hidden by another window.

Comment: Ok, so what about `Application.Run(board)` ? how can I work with that?

Comment: In WinForms the idea is that you give control to the OS using `Application.Run()`, and then respond to events.

Answer (score 0):

Okay okay, so after understanding that I can't do it "my way" (use a method called outside Board class to draw on a Form) I did some reaserch and added a timer + set `OptimizedDoubleBuffer` to `true`. Thanks to everyone that helped, if someone wants to see my existing Board class it looks like this: https://pastebin.com/CP9XRN6r (didn't want to take up space with unnecessary code), hope you'll have a great day and my post will help someone someday ^.^